# Is there a way to remove default permissions in react-native without ejecting?

Tags: react-native, android-permissions

I want to remove default android permissions in react-native app:

- *READ_PHONE_STATE*,
- *WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE*
- *READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE*.

The only way I found to do it, is to modify *AndroidManifest.xml* :

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/removing-default-permissions.

My question is: there is a way to do it without ejecting my app? As I don't want to loose the features which Expo provides.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a loot at the [docs](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/permissions/#android-permissions-equivalents-inside-appjson).

Where they say:

> Note: If you don't specify android.permissions inside your app.json, by default your standalone Android app will require all of the permissions listed above.

Also look at:

> In order to request permissions in a standalone Android app, you need to specify the corresponding native permission types in the android.permissions key inside app.json [read more about configuration](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/workflow/configuration/#android). The mapping between Permissions values and native permission types is as follows

You can add in your `app.json` only the permissions you want:

```
{
    ...
    "permissions": [ ... ]
}
```